# .NET 5 storing sensitive data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-keyvault

I have .Net Web API service that has the opportunity to save SQL integration.
For ex.:

1. Endpoint retrieves connection string of integration-DB
2. Store that in SQL DB through EF Core
3. User can retrieve the data stored in the integrated Database using WebAPI.

What will be the best approach for saving connection string (with password) for integration?
Potentially I took a look at KeyVault, but my data should be stored in the long-term period (KeyVault is short-term as I understand).
Thanks in advance

Comment: The best way is not to use a password.  Using the user credentials is the best way of being secure.

Comment: KeyValue is officially mentioned by Microsoft for storing sensitive data (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0). AWS has similar solution. Question is what kind of security do you need - it's very complex topic and there is no one-the-best solution.

Comment: There is no short-term aspect of Key Vault.  Data will stay in the Key Vault as long as you need to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recommended way to save secrets is to use Azure Key Vault.

1. [Key vault does not delete secrets on it's own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-overview).
2. Moreover, if you want you can keep [backups of Key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/backup) on regular basis.

Comment: As a result of my research I will have the next flow:
1. Get the connection string 
2. Through IDataProtector.Protect I hash the data based (that action creates Key if needed in KeyVault)
3. Save to my DB hashed connection string
4. And when I using  IDataProtector.Unprotect then key getting from KeyVault and helps to decrypt data and I able to use that.

The problem that this data can be hashed only one time and can be stored for a long time period. But KeyVault can maintain only 25KB of keys and after 90 days oldest will be removed. But for Unprotecting data in DB I need all the keys.

Comment: I guess you read it wrong, key vault does not delete secrets on it's own: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-overview

Comment: It can be deleted only when the user deletes it and purges it.